# Slow ghostscript conversion and slow printing with large ps files

Tags: performance, pdf, printing, ghostscript, postscript

I have a service which produces pdf files. I have PS-compatible printers. For printing the pdf files, I use ghostscript to convert them to ps an copy them to a shared (windows) print queue. Most of the pdf-files contain just a few pages (<10) and don't cause any trouble.

From time to time I have to print large files (100+, 500+, 5000+) pages and there I observe the following:

- converting to ps is fast for the first couple of pages, then slows down. The further the progress, the longer the time for a single page.
- after conversion, copying to the print queue works without problems
- when copying is finished and it comes to sending the document to the printer, I observe more or less the same phenomenon: the further the progress, the slower the transfer.

Here is how I convert pdf to ps:

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.07\bin\gswin64c.exe" \
-dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -DBATCH \
-sOutputFile=D:\temp\testGS\test.ps \
-sDEVICE=ps2write \
D:\temp\testGS\test.pdf
```

After this conversion I simply copy it to the print queue

```
copy /B test.ps \\printserever\myPSQueue
```

What possibilities do I have to print large files this way?

My first idea was to do the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.07\bin\gswin64c.exe" \
-dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -DBATCH \
-sOutputFile=D:\temp\testGS\test%05d.ps \
-sDEVICE=ps2write \
D:\temp\testGS\test.pdf
```

Working with single pages speeds up the conversion, it doesn't slow down after every single page, and also printing is fast, when I copy every single page as own ps file to the printer. But there is one problem I will encounter sooner or later: when I copy the single ps files, they will be single print jobs. Even when they are sorted in the correct order, if someone else starts a print job on the same printer in between, the printings will all get mixed up.

The other idea was using gsPrint, which works considerable fast, but with gsPrint I need the printer to be installed locally, which is not manageable in my environment with 300+ printers at different locations.

Can anyone tell me exactly, what happens? Is this a bad way to print? Does any have a suggestion how to solve the task of printing such documents in such an environment?

Comment: If the single page solution works it should be straightforward to reassemble into a single file so they appear as a single job.  Maybe pose that as a new question if you want to persue that -- you likely need to add a little cleanup/reset code between the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing an example PDF file its difficult to say much about why it should print slowly. However the most likely explanation is that the PDF is being rendered to an image, probably because it contains transparency.

This will result in a large image, created at the default resolution of the device (720 dpi), which is almost certainly higher than required for your printer(s). This means that a latge amount of time is spent transmitting extra data to the printer, which the PostScript interpreter in the printer then has to discard.

Using gsprint renders the file to the resolution of the device, assuming this is less than 720 dpi the resulting PostScript will be smaller therefore requiring less time to transmit, less time to decompress on the printer and less time spent throwing away extra data.

One reason the speed decreases is because of the way ps2write works, it maintains much of the final content in temporary files, and stitches the main file back together from those files. It also maintains a cross reference table which grows as the number of objects int eh file does. Unless you need the files to be continuous you could create a number of print files by using the -dFirstPage and -dLastPage options so that only a subset of the final printout is created, this might improve the performance.

Note that ps2write does not render the incoming file to an image, while gsprint definitely does, the PostScript emerging from gsprint will simply define a big bitmap. This doesn't mantain colours (everything goes to RGB) and doesn't maintain vector objects as vectors, so it doesn't scale well. However.... If you want to use gsprint to print to a remote printer, you can set up a 'virtual printer' using RedMon. You can have RedMon send the output from a port to a totally different printer, even a remote one. So you use gsprint to print to (eg) 'local instance of MyPrinter' on RedMon1: and have the RedMon port set up to capture the print stream to disk and then send the PostScript file to 'MyPrinter on another PC'. Though I'd guess thats probably not going to be any faster.

My suggestion would be to set the resolution of ps2write lower; -r300 should be enough for any printer, and lower may be possible. The resolution will only affect rendered output, everything else remains as vectors and so scales nicely. Rendered images will print perfectly well at half the resolution of the printer, in general.

Comment: Hello KenS, the PDF consists of text an tables with an Image (small b/w gif). I can't post an exact example since I don't have any examples without confidential data. Rendering with ps2write -r300 perfoms a little bit better but still the same behaviour with ps2write, so really big jobs won't work, at least on my printers here. pswrite is much faster and also printing works. pxlcolor/pxlmono also work, but printing is slow on several printer models (Lexmark T650 is slow after 3 Pages, Lexmark LEXMX410 is performing perfectly). For me I think I'll follow the pswrite/pxl path.

Comment: Thanks for the RedMon suggestion, this could solve another Problem I have.

Comment: pswrite is deprecated, and has been removed from the Ghostscript distribution. This doesn't mean that it won't work, but you'll have to build any newer versions of Ghostscript yourself in order to use it, and we won't accept any bug reports against it. The PXL devices use a totally different scheme, but I suspect these are essentially bug images. I think your problem with ps2write is simply the resources it consumes and that's due to the architecture of the code. Its not the way I'd have chosen to write it, but we're stuck with it now.

Comment: It did occur to me that by using the syntax '-sOutputFile=out%d.ps' you could create one output file per page. Because these files are DSC-compliant, you could easily then copy (or cat) those into one file and send that to your printer. Obviously you would have to try that and see if it improves your situation any, I believe that it might, particularly in terms of printing speed on the physical printers.

Comment: Hello KenS, for sure I don't want to design a solution with already deprecated devices. I tried creating one output file per page an then simply concatenated them in into one file. GSView is complaining that there are more than one %%EOF in the file. But the Printer is printing it and the perfomance seems to be OK. But I still need some more tests.

Comment: Yeah there will be multiple %%EOF comments with that approach, its a simple-minded way to work, but I was really thinking of it as a solution to your slow printing

Comment: With the printers I use, my tests have shown, that printing PS is significantly slower than with mswinpr2 or gsprint. But the printing speed depends on the specific printer. Also, printing documents with 5000+ pages works with gsprint, but not with ps2write, even when working with one output file per page and concatenating it afterwards. Sending the document to my printer is only leading to a single error page printed.

Comment: Hmm can you send me (or point to a URL) an example of the input that causes the problem, and the output file that fails on the printer ? I have to say that we never envisaged multi-thousand page files as input, its known to work with multi-hundred page files.

Comment: I just tried several other test documents with 10.000+ Pages. Those were rather simple pages with some text and some rectangles. Printing this worked when I tried sending a larger than one GB PS-file to the printer (single pages concatenated). The Version without %d caused more than one hour waiting before I cancelled the print. The "real" 5.000+ pages document caused an error (single pages). I cannot send you the "real" document and couldn't create an unclassified example. I could send you my testpage which I concatenated several thousand times - but this one worked anyway.

Comment: I'm afraid a working example doesn't really tell me anything. If you can't send a failing example, or create one which you can send, there isn't really anything more I can do or suggest.

Comment: I totally understand that. I just made a couple of tests and now I am confident that the errors with printing is a printer issue or limitation, since it depends on printer model and job size, whether the prints work or not. I'd consider your answer as correct, if you put all together: adjusting resolution, working with single pages and then concatenate. Working with single pages speeds up both, the ps2write conversion and the printing process. Also, performance is totally dependend on the printer: some print PS as fast as rastered images, others don't.

Comment: Nevertheless, here are two example pages, I contatenated them to a 5.000+ and 10.000+ pages PS document, which i can't upload since the files are too large. http://mjk.infotron.at/ps/lpb000000001.ps and http://mjk.infotron.at/ps/lpb000000002.ps

Comment: Yeah the ps2write output might well push some printers beyond their limits, especially with lots of pages and resources (fonts etc), the single page version should be better for this.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say why the printer becomes so slow with the Ghostscript generated PostScript, but you might want to give other converters a try, like `pdftops` from the Poppler utils (I found a [Windows download here](http://manifestwebdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/poppler-utils.zip) as you seem to be using Windows).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, in case I'm not successful with other devices, I'll give it a try. Using -sDEVICE=pswrite or -sDEVICE=epswrite performs much better and also printing starts, but on some printer models (e.g. Lexmark T650) it is still slower than using gsprint or -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 and the windows driver.